Missing assets on npm build for ffmpegwasm
I'm trying to run this example:
https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/tree/main/apps/vanilla-app
I have downloaded the code, navigated to the folder and then run

npm run download

as requested but it complains of

{   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
'/Users/james/Downloads/ffmpeg-2.wasm-main/scripts/download-assets.js'
] }

How is one meant to implement ffmpegwasm in this case, as the assets ist outside of the application?
